# Is every activity/fragment's xml implicitly wrapped around with a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

Let's say in an activity's xml it's using a LinearLayout as its root layout. And the activity during runtime wants to show a dialog/dialog fragment. Wouldn't the activity's xml have to be implicitly wrapped around with a FrameLayout for this to work due to needing to control the Z axis of views? Like you open the activity's xml and you see LinearLayout. However, behind the scenes, it's wrapped in a FrameLayout. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

It's complicated, and I'm honestly unable to properly explain it, but every Activity is placed in its own Window. Every Dialog attached to that Activity uses the Activity's Window to display itself.